# Is there a way to make something happen only to players with a certain value?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm setting up a loop that turns players into a certain block, but I only want certain people to be changed. Can anyone help?

Comment: By "certain value" do you mean a scoreboard objective?

Comment: Anything that will let me distinguish between players.

Answer (score 2):

To select players with a certain scoreboard value, use the `score_[SCORENAME]=[MAX]` and `score_[SCORENAME]_min=[MIN]` arguments in your entity selector. For example, to select people with a `TurnToBlock` score of at least 1:

```
@a[score_TurnToBlock_min=1]
```

You can use this in a command:

```
/say @a[score_TurnToBlock_min=1]
```

---

If by "certain value" you don't mean score values, then [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_arguments) has a full list of other arguments can select players by:

```
Argument(s)     Selection criteria
x, y, z         coordinate
r, rm           radius (max, min)
m               game mode
c               count
l, lm           experience level (max, min)
score_name      max score
score_name_min  min score
team            team name
name            entity name
dx, dy, dz      volume dimensions
rx, rxm         vertical rotation (max, min)
ry, rym         horizontal rotation (max, min)
type            entity type
```

You can use these in the same way as above. For example, to only select players in creative:

```
/say @a[m=1]
```

Comment: Thanks so much. You got it. I needed a way to only use a command on certain people.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with teams. First create two teams by doing:

> **/scoreboard teams add Block**
>
> **/scoreboard teams add NonBlock**

After doing so, using the clock that you have set up (I'm not completely sure how you did the command block clock so this might not work) change the specifier to:

> **@a[team=Block]**

That should only target the players on the non block team.
Oh, btw, you don't have to add the NonBlock team if commands aren't affecting them in the game.